# Symfony3 route 404 with Nginx server

Tags: nginx, symfony

I followed the *book* of documentation to *create my first page* : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html.

And I configured an Nginx web server for symfony according to : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#web-server-nginx

But all pages turned out to be an 404 error except the homepage.
Please help.

Comment: What does the '/var/log/nginx/project_error.log' show, and also the 'project_access.log'? Which route are you trying?

Comment: @AlvinBunk the project_access.log says  `192.168.0.2 - - [26/Jul/2016:21:52:35 +0800] "GET /lucky/number HTTP/1.1" 404 308 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"`,   and there is no error in project_error.log.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Well,  I just removed these directories: `/var/cache` `/var/logs` and `/var/sessions`, then everything went well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a permission problem...Just remove `/var/cache` `/var/logs` and `/var/sessions`, everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

This link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
Describes how to setup permissions for your web server.

In particular, for Linux you would run:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

I'm not sure if you are using MacOS, but there is a different set of commands as shown in the above link.

Comment: I built it on a Linux virtual machine. And I followed those commands above. Now I solved this by removing directories under `/var/`. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should click the up arrow to indicate I help - if indeed I did help. Thanks!